# Implementing google in-app subscription

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

The developer guide gives the sample for in-app billing, and for the subscription it takes for the same sample application, and saying to modify it for subscription.I want to modify this "Dungeons" sample application for subscription, But in the developer guide there is no info for modifying this sample to subscription. What should i change for same.I want to know complete steps for modifying this sample. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have tried any thing? It is not much difference then inApp purchase. For `subscription` you will make request like `mBillingService.requestPurchase(productId,
       Consts.ITEM_TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION, null)`

Comment: I am totally new for implementing google subscriptions. Can you please give me steps that how can i implement subscription in my app.

Comment: have you implement `InApp Product purchase` in your app? If not start from here http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download

Comment: Yes, i have done the in-app implementation with sample "Dungeons" application.But i don't know how to change it for subscription for monthly or yearly basis. Also how can i know that user has subscribed  for the app every time he uses the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you implement your `InApp Product Purchase` with old billing API.
then

1. update the billing API code to version 2
2. not much change in the `InApp subscription`. other then `mBillingService.requestPurchase(productId, Consts.ITEM_TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION, null)`
3. To check subscribed items, you can use `Restore purchases`. In App subscriptions also act as a `InApp Products'

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help.But i have done this with sample application "Dungeons".I want to implement it with my application.what changes i need to do in my app.